# Share_plus plugin - Error: Call requires API level 22 (current min is 16): android.content.Intent#createChooser [NewApi]

Tags: flutter, gradle

My flutter version: Flutter 3.0.0
Gradle version: Gradle 7.2

when I run `.../android$ ./gradlew clean` and then `.../android$ ./gradlew build -warning-mode all` in terminal, I get the following error:

```
> Task :share_plus:lintDebug FAILED
Lint found 4 errors, 3 warnings. First failure:

/home/my-name/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/share_plus-6.2.0/android/src/main/kotlin/dev/fluttercommunity/plus/share/Share.kt:68: Error: Call requires API level 22 (current min is 16): android.content.Intent#createChooser [NewApi]
            Intent.createChooser(
```

I changed minSdkVersion like the following but it is still not working.

android/app/build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.citymarker"
        minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
        targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

android/local.properties:

```
sdk.dir=/home/my-name/Android/Sdk
flutter.sdk=/home/thiago/development/flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1

flutter.minSdkVersion=23
flutter.targetSdkVersion=33
flutter.compileSdkVersion=33
```

I tried everything I could, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using a lower version of share_plus plugin. Just add the below line in your pubspec.yaml under dependencies:

share_plus: 4.0.2

I don't know yet why the error was happening even after changing minSdkVersion to 23. If someone has an answer, please, share with us.

Answer (score 0):

under External Libraries you can find all the libraries u r using including share_plus (these are the files generated when u run 'flutter pub get'). U need to update share_plus/android/build.gradle with minSdkVersion 23, and it should build.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHNRu.png)

Comment: This is a bad temporary fix. To fix this update the project's minimum SDK version to 22 because the package share_plus does not support SDKs lower than 22.
This can be found under android/app/build.gradle

Comment: Hey Marcos, thanks for the comment, but I have a minSdkVersion of 23 for the project and still it generates share_plus with minSdkVersion of 16 after running 'flutter pub get' for some reason. Do u know how to fix that?

Comment: As long as the package supports your project's SDK version, you don't need to worry about the package's minSdkVersion . The rule of thumb i:s A project and a 3rd party package are compatible if your application's minSdkVersion is higher or equal to the 3rd party application's minSdkVersion.

Do not edit the 3rd party package minSdkVersion, edit your project's which can be found here: android/app/build.gradle